# javascript popup stop after some time

Tags: php, javascript, asp-classic

I have created a simple javascript popup which will ask user to wait for 10 mins or continue to process. In my php site I already put a condition if time is less than 10 mins then only the pop up should appear. I need to write a another function for the javascript to popup only for 10mins even after refreshing the page, and after that it should not appear. as I am new to javascript, I could not get the right function to overcome it. really appreciate your help, thanks

This is my popup code:

```
function confirmation() {
    var answer = confirm("You are trying to payment again, please wait for 10 mins to avoid duplicate payment. Click OK to wait and Cancel to continue pay")
    if (answer){
        alert("Thank you for waiting,please check your mail in 10 minutes, if you did not recieve any mail, proceed to purchase again.")
            document.formDealPayment.submit();
    }
    else{
        alert("Thank You.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Place ; at each line end

Comment: Use a COOKIE variable along with your javascript code. and check value of cookie in case user refreshes page also.

Comment: You can check out JavaScript timer events. It may only solve half of your problem, but halfway is better than noway. 

[Timer Event](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Comment: thanks for your help guys, i tried the timer event..but does not reach my expectation..but thank u for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it server side, as client side JavaScript can't know by itself what is the server time and how long has passed since the user last refreshed the page. (Except for cookies, but it's an overkill here)

Not really sure how PHP and Classic ASP come together, but simple classic ASP code that will call the function only if 10 minutes passed is:

```
If (10 minutes passed) Then
    Response.Write("<script type=""text/javascript"">confirmation();</script>")
End If
```